# jquery enable submit button while start typing on the last field

Tags: jquery

I am able to disable the submit button before all the input fields filled.
But, I need to enable the submit button once user starts typing on **last input field**.(But need to check before all the fields are filled while entering the last field)

### last input field:

```
<input type="password" class="passwd" />
```

### jquery

```
function init(){
        $form = $('#signupFrm'); // cache
        $form.find('a.submit').addClass('disableClick');

        $form.find(':input').change(function() { // monitor all inputs for changes
            var disable = false;
            $form.find(':input').each(function(i, el) { // test all inputs for values
                if ($.trim(el.value) === '') {
                    disable = true; // disable submit if any of them are still blank
                }
            });
            if(disable == true)
                $form.find('a.submit').addClass('disableClick');
            else
                $form.find('a.submit').removeClass('disableClick');
        });
    }
```

is is there any way to enable the button using jquery **keyPress**

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: Do you want all input fields to be filled before showing the submit button?
Because if you do, your accepted answer does not give that, because if you fill your password input and left a field of more blank "above" the button will show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to do this

```
$("input[type=text],select,textarea,input[type=password]").on('keyup blur change', function () { 
    $("input[type=text],textarea,input[type=password]").each(function(){
        if($(this).val().trim()=="")
        {
            $form.find('a.submit').addClass('disableClick');
        }
        else
        {
            $form.find('a.submit').addClass('disableClick');
        }
    });
});
```

**Updated Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/Isakkiraj/xj9gzpqz/1/

Comment: I do not agree introducing the `if` clause inside `each`. This break the check before all the fields are filled while entering the last field.

Comment: i added 'keyup' and 'blur' inside on event, its working fine. $form.find(':input').on('change keyup blur', function() {})

Answer (score 1):

Change a little "change" to "keyup".

```
$form.find(':input').keyup(function() {
     // same code
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0bntak8b/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use this:

```
$( "target" ).on('keyup', function() {
    init();
});
```

You have already written the whole code for handling your conditions in the `init()`. So you just need to call it on the `keyup` event on the input having `passwd` class.

Check the plunkr "http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAvjJFkCnhRFgJj44zkJ". Here on `keyup` event some functionality can be performed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `keypress` and `form submit`

this jquery

```
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#print').toggle(!($('input.required').length == $('input.required').filter(

function () {
    return this.value;
}).length));
});
$( "#last_input" ).keypress(function() {
$('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vddkjksc/)

Answer (score 0):

just break loop and disable when you encounter any of the input is blank

```
    function init()
    {
        $form = $('#signupFrm'); // cache
        $form.find('a.submit').addClass('disableClick');

    $form.find(':input').change(function()
    { 
        // monitor all inputs for changes
        var disable = false;
        $form.find(':input').each(function(i, el)
        { 
            // test all inputs for values
            if ($.trim(el.value) === '')
            {
                disable = true; 
                    // disable submit if any of them are still blank
                return false; 
                    //if any of the input is blank just disable submit button
            }
        });
        if(disable == true)
        {
            $form.find('a.submit').addClass('disableClick');
        }
        else
        {
            $form.find('a.submit').removeClass('disableClick');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: i added 'keyup' and 'blur' inside on event, its working fine. $form.find(':input').on('change keyup blur', function() {})

Comment: Glad it helped you.
kindly accept right answer as accepeted answer.